# Design issues with a controller construct managing different component implementations

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates, factory-pattern

I am wrapping my head around on a relatively simple problem, but seemingly cannot find a way to resolve this issue - even a bit hackish ..., I just got stuck and could use some idea that seem not to pop up. The code sample shown below is NOT (fully) working and is rather there to show my problem.

I have a controller class with 3 methods `init`, `process` and `dispose`. The Controller basically is a wrapper for one or more so called components to be executed.

Furthermore there is a `component_manager` class to create component instances and manage their life cycle. The component manager is derived from an interface defining 4 virtual methods, such as `init`, `prepare`, `recycle` and `dispose`.

A component itself also has a well defined interface `icomponent`. All components derive from that interface and all components are default constructable (no arguments needed).

To show some code I've extracted the important parts from the code I am experimenting with, leaving out the `controller' wrapper class and all the noise around it.

```cc
namespace detail {

// Iterator for std::tuple    
template<typename Tuple, typename F, std::size_t ...Indices>
constexpr void for_each_impl(Tuple&& tuple, F&& f, std::index_sequence<Indices...>) 
{
    using swallow = int[];
    (void)swallow{1,
        (f(std::get<Indices>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))), void(), int{})...
    };
}

} // Namespace detail

template<typename Tuple, typename F>
constexpr void for_each(Tuple&& tuple, F&& f) 
{
    constexpr std::size_t N = std::tuple_size<std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>>::value;
    detail::for_each_impl(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple), std::forward<F>(f),
        std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
} 

// A component
class icomponent {
public:
    virtual ~icomponent() = default;
    virtual std::string id() = 0; 
};

// Sample components a, b and c
class component_a : public icomponent { 
public:    
    virtual std::string id() override { return "component a"; } 
};
class component_b : public icomponent { 
public:    
    virtual std::string id() override { return "component b"; } 
};
class component_c : public icomponent { 
public:    
    virtual std::string id() override { return "component c"; } 
};

// Interface defining a component manager
class iprocessing_component_manager
{
public:
    virtual ~iprocessing_component_manager() = default;

    virtual T* prepare() = 0;

    // More members like init(), recycle() and dispose()
};

// An simple, possible implementation of component manager
class simple_processing_component_manager 
    : public iprocessing_component_manager
{
public:
    virtual ~simple_processing_component_manager() = default;

    // ... other implemented methods ...

    virtual T* prepare()
    {
        // ... creation of component
    }
};

// In the controller wrapper, the process method
template<typename ...T>
void process()
{
    // This initialization is normally within the controller wrapper
    std::unique_ptr<simple_processing_component_manager> component_mgr = std::make_unique<simple_processing_component_manager>();

    // Convert to tuple
    std::tuple<T...> components;

    // Iterate over (component) types ...
    for_each(components, [&](auto& comp) {  

       using component_t = typename std::remove_reference<decltype(comp)>::type;

       // Steps would be ...

       // Instantiate the component (doesn't work, just showing what I need to accomplish)
       component_t* x = component_mgr->prepare<component_t>();
       //                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

       // Perform component execution ... here I just print the id of the component
       std::cout << x->id() << "\n";

       // After processing component_mgr recycle() and / or dispose() are called
       delete x;
    });
}
```

Putting it all together, a typical controller usage would look like this:

```cc
controller c(/* some initialization parameters */);
result = c->process<component_a, component_c>(/* some more parameters */);
```

That would be my preferred way of usage, passing the components as variadic template arguments. Within the controller `process` method, these component types are iterated and executed. I would really like to pass the components with the `process` method and not with the controller instantiation.

My basic problem relies in component managers `prepare` method. A simple implementation of a `component_manager` and its `prepare` method would look like this:

```cc
T* prepare(/*...*/)
{
    return new T(); // Create component instance
}
```

However, I will have different implementations of component managers, for example, I would like to recycle and reuse the created component pointers by using an object pool. In such case I may have something like

```cc
return borrow_object<T>(/* some key */); // Get from pool, will be returned back to pool with `recycle`...
```

A the end I will have various distinct `component_managers` and each implementation of `prepare` and the other recycle/disposal methods will differ, however, for all cases I need the component type `T`. But ... a template method cannot be virtual. I am aware of this!

Is there any way to fix the above problem or perhaps a way better approach or design for this problem? I been sitting and staring at this too long, so please bear with me if I missed something really simple.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert of inheritance and virtual methods... and I'm not sure to understand your exact requirements... anyway, as you said, a template method cannot be virtual.

So you have to take in count this.

But a template method can call a virtual method in a template class.

So I propose to make virtual `prepare()` in `iprocessing_component_manager` to return a `icomponent` pointer.

```
struct iprocessing_component_manager
 {
   virtual ~iprocessing_component_manager () = default;

   virtual icomponent * prepare () = 0;
 };
```

Next, to prepare a single type template derived class that implement `prepare()`

```
template <typename T>
struct type_processing_component_manager
   : public iprocessing_component_manager
 {
   virtual ~type_processing_component_manager () = default;

   virtual T* prepare () override
    { return new T; }
 };
```

Observe that `prepare()` return a pointer to `T`, not a pointer to `icomponent`.

Now you can write a variadic template `tuple_processing_component_manager`, that inherit from all `type_processing_component_manager<Ts>`, with a template (not `virtual`, obviously) `prepare()` that call the right (type dependent) virtual inherited `prepare()` method.

```
template <typename ... Ts>
struct tuple_processing_component_manager
   : public type_processing_component_manager<Ts>...
 {
   virtual ~tuple_processing_component_manager () = default;

   template <typename T>
   T * prepare ()
    { return type_processing_component_manager<T>::prepare(); }
 };
```

In the main `process()` you can have a `component_mgr` based over the variadic processing component manager

```
auto component_mgr
 { std::make_unique<tuple_processing_component_manager<Ts...>>() };
```

and use it, in the lambda, as follows

```
  using component_t
     = typename std::remove_reference<decltype(comp)>::type;

  std::unique_ptr<component_t> x
   { component_mgr->template prepare<component_t>() };

  std::cout << x->id() << "\n";
```

The following is a full working example.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

namespace detail
 {
   template <typename Tuple, typename F, std::size_t ... Is>
   constexpr void for_each_impl (Tuple && tuple, F && f,
                                 std::index_sequence<Is...>) 
    {
      using swallow = int[];

      (void)swallow { 1,
         ((void)f(std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))), 0)... };
    }
 }

template <typename Tuple, typename F>
constexpr void for_each (Tuple && tuple, F && f) 
 {
   constexpr auto N 
    { std::tuple_size<std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>>::value };

   detail::for_each_impl(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple), std::forward<F>(f),
                         std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
 } 

struct icomponent
 {
   virtual ~icomponent () = default;

   virtual std::string id () = 0; 
 };

struct component_a : public icomponent
 { virtual std::string id () override { return "component a"; } };

struct component_b : public icomponent
 { virtual std::string id () override { return "component b"; } };

struct component_c : public icomponent
 { virtual std::string id () override { return "component c"; } };

struct iprocessing_component_manager
 {
   virtual ~iprocessing_component_manager () = default;

   virtual icomponent * prepare () = 0;
 };

template <typename T>
struct type_processing_component_manager
   : public iprocessing_component_manager
 {
   virtual ~type_processing_component_manager () = default;

   virtual T* prepare () override
    { return new T; }
 };

template <typename ... Ts>
struct tuple_processing_component_manager
   : public type_processing_component_manager<Ts>...
 {
   virtual ~tuple_processing_component_manager () = default;

   template <typename T>
   T * prepare ()
    { return type_processing_component_manager<T>::prepare(); }
 };

template <typename ... Ts>
void process ()
 {
   auto component_mgr
    { std::make_unique<tuple_processing_component_manager<Ts...>>() };

   std::tuple<Ts...> components;

   for_each(components, [&](auto& comp)
    {  
      using component_t
         = typename std::remove_reference<decltype(comp)>::type;

      std::unique_ptr<component_t> x
       { component_mgr->template prepare<component_t>() };

      std::cout << x->id() << "\n";
    });
}

int main ()
 {
   process<component_a, component_b, component_c>();
 }
```

If you're not interested in the `std::tuple` of `components`, and in `for_each()` processing, you can use directly the `type_processing_component_manager` struct in a recursive `process()`

```
// ground case
template <int = 0>
void process ()
 { }

// recursive case
template <typename T0, typename ... Ts>
void process ()
 {
   type_processing_component_manager<T0> component_mgr;

   std::unique_ptr<T0> x { component_mgr.prepare() };

   std::cout << x->id() << "\n";

   // recursion
   process<Ts...>();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the approach, it looks promising. Problem are the 3 other virtual methods `init`, `recycle` and `dispose` which also need an implementation, but these do not need the `T` parameter. The `recycle` method only expects the pointer (created by `prepare`) some time later in the controller wrapper (not within in 'process') to either delete or recycle it. The other mentioned methods are used on controller wrapper level, thus the processing_component_manager has to be instantiated on controller wrapper level (not within process), but on controller level, I do not know `T`. Any hint on that?

Comment: OK, I think I found a good way. Instead of passing the component types as a variadic template argument to the `prepare` method - actually that would have been my preferred way - I pass the them into the wrapping controller class and the `component_mgr` instance as a class member. With this I have access to to the component_mgr from the controller and its entire processing life cycle. I implemented the 3 other remaining component_mgr methods, mentioned in my comment above,  in your ` tuple_processing_component_manager`.  The test code seems to work so far. Thanks again for your ideas!